# How to test if an SVG element is contained by another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I want to know how I can extract the information if one element in the SVG DOM tree contained in a different element of the same tree.

In my case I want to execute onClick events on the different elements of the SVG tree. Since the SVG graph is issued by a server and contains several thousand elements I thought it is not feasible to register a distinct event with each node. So my idea was to register the event with the root node of the SVG and then determine from the target of the event which element was clicked on. This works fine so far.

In the next step I want to open a pop-up frame to display information about the SVG element I clicked on. The frame shouldn't open when the event came from an area of the SVG image where no element is placed.

After reading the documentation I thought it would be a good idea to use the jQuery method contains (http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) however it yields false as a result all the time and I don't know what is wrong. The `($(svgRoot).find(svgElement).length` method also does not work. Does someone has an idea what is wrong?

Here is an example of the problem in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gjvaz346/1/

Here is the SVG graph:

```
<svg id="svg-element" currentScale="1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">  
    <g id="svg-root" transform="scale(0.5)">
        <rect id="blue-rectangle" style='fill:blue;opacity:1' x='10' y='10' width='70' height='40' />
        <rect id="green-rectangle" style='fill:green;opacity:1' x='60' y='30' width='40' height='40' />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here is the event handler method:

```
function svgCanvasClicked(evt) {

    var target = evt.target;
    var svgElement = $(target.id);
    var svgRoot = $('#svg-root');

    console.log(target.id);
    console.log(svgRoot.id);

    console.log($(svgRoot).find(svgElement).length);
    console.log($.contains(svgRoot, svgElement));
}
```

Greetings

Comment: Just compare `target` to `this`, true in case svg element is directly clicked, false otherwise. See [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gjvaz346/3/). Other way would be to just delegate event to any descendant: `$('#svg-element').on('click', '*', handler);`. Only called if you click on some descendant of svg, not the svg element itself

Comment: EDIT: `$('#svg-element').on('click', 'rect', svgCanvasClicked);`. Only called if you click on some descendant `rect` of svg, not the svg element itself

Comment: Well that was relatively easy. Can you give a proper answer so I can accept it? Maybe you can elaborate why my methods don't work right. Now it seems like a stupid question but I'm unexperienced with JavasScript so I wasn't aware that you can use the equals operator that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to bind `click` event on `rect` element but delegating it to `svg` element, so only one event would be bound:

```
$('#svg-element').on('click', 'rect', handler);
```

Then inside `handler` method, `this` will refer to the clicked `rect`;

### Updated jsFiddle

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I changed it in my code so it reacts to a specific class not the rect-element which seems to works also. Now I have to adapt the webservice so that it sets the class attribute for the elements. I wonder if this is a good idea to delegate this functionality to the webservice but that seems to be a different question.